# Google Drive branding policy

Tags: google-drive-api

This question is not directly related with programming or software development but since this is the official Google Drive SDK support platform I'm placing it on SO.

I am the publisher of an Android application that is distributed in the usual Free/Pro format (where the Pro version provides many more features than the Free version).

At this moment I'm planning to integrate the application with Google Drive but only in the Pro version. The Free version will still show the buttons and the Google Drive branding, but as the user tries to interact it will show a message stating that the feature is only available in Pro version with the respective link to the Pro application version.

Now the question itself:
Is it legal (or allowed) for the Free application version to show the Google Drive branding, since its just advertising and not in fact integrating? If not, how should I advertise the Google Drive integration (from the Free version) that is included in the Pro version? The fancy Google Drive branding is essential to capture user attention at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is legal, but please make sure to check the [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/drive/branding) and [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/drive/terms).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if it is free to develop the application using the google resources/access there won't be any copyright issue it is just that application will have extra functionality provided by pro version which gonna work with google drive. From a user point of view I would just say that it looks like dragging money out of people by charging them extra for little effort that is putted for extra functionality

Comment: About your last sentence: The Free version has almost all the functionality that the Pro version offers. The Pro version only offers these "tiny" extra bits that are not crucial for application functionality. I spend many hours trying to keep things perfect and implement all user suggestions in Free version. That's what took the Free version to a high download count and excellent rating. From a publisher point of view this looks like a way to donate and keep application development and improvement, instead of demanding for functionality without caring about the developer effort